# LINQ search List<string[]>; if [0] matches then return [1]

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a way to do this more efficiently with LINQ? I think there might need to be a ternary-if to accommodate the empty string, and I am mostly looking for the correct LINQ syntax to match [a] and return [b] (if there is one). I searched without finding anything, but that's on me because I couldn't really think of what to search for...

```
public static string getValue(List<string[]> input, string searchCriteria)
{
    if (input.Count < 1)
    {
        return "";
    }
    for (int temp = 0; temp < input.Count; temp++)
    {
        if(input[temp][0].Equals(searchCriteria))
        {
            return input[temp][1];
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to use a `List<string[]>` rather than a `Dictionary<string, string>`?

Comment: You seem to be under the assumption that shorter code is automatically more efficient. That assumption is wrong. Do you want to ask about a more efficient solution, or about a shorter solution?

Comment: @hvd There is more than one context of efficiency. I was referring to development efficiency, not processing. But yes, the shorter solution that increases efficiency in development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I would use. <strike>I couldn't think of a one-liner because `.FirstOrDefault` on an `IEnumerable<string>` returns `null` if the collection is empty, rather than `""`.</strike> I just found a better way, using the null-coalescing operator (`??`), that is a one-liner:

```
public static string getValue(List<string[]> input, string searchCriteria)
{
    return (from arr in input
            where arr[0] == searchCriteria
            select arr[1]).FirstOrDefault() ?? "";
}
```

However, this seems like it would be better suited for a `Dictionary<string, string>`, in which case it would just be:

```
public static string getValue(Dictionary<string, string> input, string searchCriteria)
{
    return input.ContainsKey(searchCriteria) ? input[searchCriteria] : "";
}
```

Comment: Jashaszun, you're awesome. While this was mostly a syntax question, I definitely recognize the advantage of a dictionary in this instance. Thank you.

Comment: @Wes Glad I could help.